# How should I help my users find my business from a mobile site?

Tags: mobile, dictionary

First time developing a responsive website for my restaurant. I have a link on my navbar that says "Locate Us". I was thinking that when the mobile phone user clicks that link, it will give them directions to the restaurant via the phone's GPS or something.

I don't know much about this. What is the current industry standard for helping users find a restaurant or business via their mobile phone? Do I just make a regular link to a google map or is there something better?

Note: I'm using Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

in modern browsers there is the possibility to do geo-location lookups.

you could then link this kind of stuff to an external map application or implement it yourself with googlemaps or thelike.

here is a well made article about geolocation: http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd keep it simple and use the built in [HTML5 `<address>` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/address.html):

```
<address>
   <span>Street Address</span>
   <span>City, State ZIP</span>
</address>
```

Most smart phones will make `<address>` blocks click-able and preset the user with options as to how to handle the address (i.e. with Google Maps, etc).